# Should I delete the cgi-bin folder in a subdomain I just created?

Tags: subdomain, cgi-bin

Using cpanel on my hosting account, I created a subdomain - e.g. [www.clothing.mysite.com](http://www.clothing.mysite.com)

A cgi-bin folder was automatically created in the directory for clothing.mysite.com.  Do I need it?  I'm only using the subdomain to install wordpress on it.  I don't really understand what the cgi-bin folder is for and I'm happy to leave it if it doesn't harm anything.  Any thoughts?

Comment: delete it along with all the _anoying frontpage server extention files

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You can safely delete it. "cgi-bin" is hardly ever used these days.

Comment: It's good that you gave the brief answer first, but it's important to give some explanation. Without that, people can only trust that you're right.

Answer (score 103):

`cgi-bin` historically was the only place where executable or script code (binaries, shell scripts, etc.) could be stored. It is mostly a historic relic since most hosts allow execution of scripts from anywhere.

Answer (score 17):

You can **safely delete** "cgi-bin" folder, it's hardly ever used nowadays

Also beware that when your server got some malware scripts scans different folders and then hides on folders like cgi-bin because they rarely are checked now.

I even wrote a script before that "monitors" different folders in my server and alerts me if it found different scripts in there on my personal and clients servers too.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen it mentioned but it might also be worth noting that since cgi-bin is traditionally used to execute scripts, some hosting providers might require you to edit your **.htaccess** file if you wish to execute scripts outside cgi-bin (same is true if you deleted your cgi-bin).