# Codeigniter: from localhost to webserver

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, web

Helllo everybody. I am desperatly trying to get codeigniter run on a webserver. The apache mod_rewrite is enabled, and I tried almost everything related i found on the internet, but nothing worked.

The directory on the webserver is

[image]

The cgi-bin folder have been already there. Posts that i have read said, the cgi-bin folder is irrelevant since [it is hardly used these days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321572/should-i-delete-the-cgi-bin-folder-in-a-subdomain-i-just-created).
But here is the first question: Holds this for me, too? Which .htaccess File should i use? Why is an .htaccess file put there?

None of them seems to work:
I tried several settings and I ended up with the following version for both .htaccess files:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test94252.test-account.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test94252.test-account.com/index.htm [L]
</IfModule>
```

My goal is simply that if i call the domain http://website.com/ that /website/application/views/index.php is called.
What is wrong with this .htaccess file?

EDIT: on my local machine i go by http://localhost/website/Controller/Function for calling that index.php file.

Please note: For the sake of testing i put a index.htm into /website/ to check whether the redirect is done, but it is not working.

I am looking forward hearing from you.

Comment: Hi, is the folder "website" located in the public_html folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***First:***

No, you should safe-delete it. `cgi-bin` historically was the only place where executable or script code (binaries, shell scripts, etc.) could be stored. It is mostly a historic relic since most hosts allow execution of scripts from anywhere.

When a .htaccess file is placed in a directory which is in turn 'loaded via the Apache Web Server', then the .htaccess file is detected and executed by the Apache Web Server software.
`.htaccess` can be content password protection or image hot link prevention.

***Second:***

You should edit `.htaccess` in `./website` folder.

***And:***

My file `.htaccess` run in server like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

**Updated:**

Let tried again with another method.

1. Make below changes in `application/config.php` file

   ```
   $config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/Your Ci folder_name';
   $config['index_page'] = '';
   $config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
   ```
2. Make `.htaccess` file in your root directory using below code

   ```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
   ```

Note: remove `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c></IfModule>`

Comment: thank you vanloc, so if i understand this right i can go with any .htaccess file since it does not matter where it is located. But still it is not working. When i look at your file it is partwise similar to https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html. But I don't understand how I'm going to tell apace where to find /application/views/index.php

Comment: It is directing to /index.htm, like there wouldn't be any .htaccess file

Comment: thank you for your effort. i checked and updated all values in config and removed the tag <ifMod...>. But still no effect, that means /index.htm is loaded.

Comment: Try checking in `application/config/routes.php`. Please post values of your `$route['default_controller']` and `application/config/config.php` at line: `$config['base_url']`

Comment: $route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view'; Till now i have never thought about the default_controller.

Comment: your way seems to be the solution in most cases, as i could recognize from crawling through the web for a solution, but somehow it is not working, yet. :(

Comment: It is working. Right now i am out of time but your solution is correct. the problem were something else. I'll pick a moment of quit to give a full explanation of my problem in a couple of days. Thank you very much again for your comprehensive solution.

Comment: You are welcome. I very excited when my answer is helpful for you